# Prevent field from being queried in graphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm new to graphQL, so I apologize if this is simple. I have the following `schema.graphql`:

```
type MyObjInput {
    id: ID!
    createdDate: String
}

type MyObj {
    id: ID!
    databaseId: String
    createdDate: String
}

type Query {
    """
    Retrieves a previously created MyObj
    """
    getMyObj(id: ID!): MyObj!
}

type Mutation {
    """
    Creates a new MyObj
    """
    createMyObj(initialObj: MyObjInput): MyObj!
}
```

Basically when someone queries `createMyObj`, I call an external API to populate the `databaseId` field, create the `MyObj` object, and persist it locally. I need this `databaseId` to do some additional functionalities internally later on.

However, when someone queries `getMyObj`, I don't want to expose the `databaseId` field (ie) I want to make sure nobody is able to query that field. Is there an easy way of making sure nobody can query that field? And if not, is the best alternative to have 2 separate objects, one that is used internally, and the other that is sent to the client?

I did see some examples of using schema-directives (https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-directives), but that looks like it does dynamic transformation, and I'm not sure how I can use that to prevent someone from querying the field in the first place.

I'm using apollo server, with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options i can think of:

1. Return a different object for public consumption (together with a new output type)
2. Use the same output type, but add a resolver (https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/resolvers) for this private field. You can then do some permission checks in the resolver method for the affected fields.

Here is some pseudo code for option 2:

```
const resolverMap = {
  MyObj: {
    databaseId(myObj) {
      if (hasAccess(myObj)) return myObj.databaseId
      return null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But option 2 here still means that a client can query for that field, correct? They would just get back a null value. I wanted to see if it is possible to hide the existence of the field from the client.

Comment: But why is the field in the schema if it shouldn't be queryable by *any* client? How are you using it internally? I don't think you can have a field which is not queryable *at all*. You can probably hide it from introspection (https://www.useanvil.com/blog/engineering/undocumented-directive/) or throw an error instead of returning null (to make it more clear)

Comment: Yea, I looked at that blog post from anvil, but they are using an older version. That support has been deprecated in the newer version. I am going ahead with having them as two separate objects. Thanks!